# Why balance doesn't change after paypal transaction completing

Tags: php, paypal, symfony-2.5

I'm using "Omnipay integration with PayPal Express Checkout [symfony2.5]"
and this the implimentation for the class

namespace Atcop\BookBundle\Libs;

use Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory;

class Paypal  {

```
protected $gateway = null;
private static $CURRENCY = "USD";

public function __construct() {

    $this->gateway = GatewayFactory::create('PayPal_Express');
    $this->gateway->setUsername('*********');
    $this->gateway->setPassword('**********');
    $this->gateway->setSignature('**************');
    $this->gateway->setTestMode(true);
}
public function sendPurchase($parameters = []){

    $payArray = [
        'amount' => 58.00,
        'description' => $parameters['description'],
        'currency' => self::$CURRENCY,
        'transactionId' => $parameters['transactionId'],
        'returnUrl' => $parameters['returnUrl'],
        'cancelUrl' => $parameters['cancelUrl']
    ];

    return $this->gateway->purchase($payArray)->send();
}

public function complete($reference, $payerId) {

    $completePayData = [
        'amount' => 58.00,
        'description' => 'Buy the currencies book - step by step',
        'transactionReference' => $reference,
        'payerId' => $payerId,
    ];

    $response = $this->gateway->completePurchase($completePayData)->send();
    if($response->isSuccessful()){
        return $response->getData();
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Everything is ok after completing and i see the notifications and the receipt for that transaction in the dashboard but the balance doesn't change in merchant and buyer ???!!!

Comment: I've only used the JavaScript SDK but in that there is a separate "capture" step after the transaction has been approved.

Comment: capture step after complete ??

Comment: Try looking at the SDK samples for your SDK.  What I said is for PayPal's own "buttons" JavaScript SDK not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved
the balance doesn't change on test mode, when converted to live mode every things were ok.